# Implicit Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was just wondering where the y'/(dy/dx) in implicit differentiation comes from.
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 25
$$
$$
(d/dx) x^2 + (d/dy) y^2 **(dy/dx)** = 25 (d/dx)
$$
$$
2x + 2y (dy/dx) = 0
$$
$$
(dy/dx) = -x/y
$$
Where does the bold part come from? Wikipedia says it's a byproduct of the chain rule, but it's just not clicking for me.

Comment: When you do implicit differentiation what you're doing is assuming $y(x)$ (that $y$ is a function of $x$).  Then you're viewing the equation $x^2+y^2=25$ as an equality between functions of $x$ -- it's just that the right-hand side is the constant function $25$.  So you differentiate the left and right-hand sides. The derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $x$ is $2yy'$ by the chain rule.

Comment: Where does the bold part go to?

Comment: It's the part with the *****(dy/dx)***** around it. Someone has altered the formatting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you implicitly differentiate $x^2+y^2=25$, you are differentiating with respect to a particular variable—in this case, $x$, so:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+y^2)&=\frac{d}{dx}25
\\
\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)+\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)&=0
\\
2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}&=0
\\
2y\frac{dy}{dx}&=-2x
\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=-\frac{x}{y}
\end{align}$$

From the 3rd line to the 4th line, $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)$ is the derivative with respect to $x$ of $y^2$, in which (as in Ryan Budney's comment) we assume that $y$ is some function of $x$, so we apply the chain rule, differentiating $y^2$ with respect to $y$ and multiplying by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ to get $2y\frac{dy}{dx}$.

---

*edit*: Based on the comments below, I think it might be useful if I introduced a slightly different notation: Let $D_x$ be the [differential operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) with respect to $x$, which you have previously written as $\frac{d}{dx}$ (and, similarly, $D_y$ is the differential operator with respect to $y$).  When we apply the differential operator to something, we read and write it like a function: $D_x(x^2)=2x$ is "the derivative with respect to $x$ of $x^2$ is $2x$."

Now, rewriting the work above in this notation:

$$\begin{align}
D_x(x^2+y^2)&=D_x(25)
\\
D_x(x^2)+D_x(y^2)&=0
\\
2x+D_y(y^2)D_x(y)&=0
\\
2x+2yD_x(y)&=0
\\
2yD_x(y)&=-2x
\\
D_x(y)=\frac{dy}{dx}&=-\frac{x}{y}
\end{align}$$

And, to your question of finding $\frac{dx}{dy}$:
$$\begin{align}
D_y(x^2+y^2)&=D_y(25)
\\
D_y(x^2)+D_y(y^2)&=0
\\
D_x(x^2)D_y(x)+2y&=0
\\
2xD_y(x)+2y&=0
\\
2xD_y(x)&=-2y
\\
D_y(x)=\frac{dx}{dy}&=-\frac{y}{x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: So, would (d/dy) x^2 (dx/dy) + (d/dx) y^2 = 25 (d/dy) --> 2x (dx/dy) + 2y = 0 --> (dy/dx) = -y/x be an equally valid answer?

Comment: @Ryan: Sort of.  It's correct in this setting (I think $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$ is true when dealing with a curve in the x-y plane) but it's not really "proper" in that you should not treat $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}$ as fractions that are reciprocals of one another.  That is, if you were a student of mine in a first-year calculus course, I'd give you most or all of the credit, but you'd also get a note that you shouldn't do it that way and should differentiate with respect to the correct variable.

Comment: Sorry, what I had meant was if they had asked you to solve for dx/dy, would what I put there have been correct?

Comment: @Ryan: ahh... In the first step, I think you have (d/dy) and (d/dx) swapped on the left side and the 25 should be after d/dy on the right side, and in the last step, I think you meant dx/dy.  That is, I think it should be: ((d/dx) (x^2)) (dx/dy) + (d/dy)(y^2) = (d/dy)(25) --> 2x (dx/dy) + 2y = 0 --> (dx/dy) = -y/x

Comment: Ah, ok, I see how I messed up. Thank you!

Comment: I feel as though I'm still missing something, and it's probably very elementary. I'm still not understanding how exactly Dx(y^2) in line two, becomes Dy(y^2)Dx(y) in line three.

Comment: @Ryan: Written in the notation I introduced, the chain rule is more or less Dx(whatever)=Dy(whatever)Dx(y).  In evaluating Dx(y^2), we're working as if y is a function of x, so by the chain rule, we can differentiate y^2 with respect to y and multiply by the derivative of y with respect to x.  Put another way, the chain rule is often expressed as: if h(x)=f(g(x)), then h'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x); in the case of Dx(y^2), f(y)=y^2 and g(x)=y(x), so h(x)=(y(x))^2 and h'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)=2(y(x))y'(x).

Comment: Thank you! I knew what the chain rule did, but seeing it written out in f(x) notation got the idea through. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Ryan: You're welcome.  I think it's easier to get a handle on the chain rule when differentiating things like sin(x^2) or e^(sin(x)) than when it comes up in implicit differentiation.

Comment: sorry...why are we finding derivative of y2 in respect to dy and not dx as in ((d/dy)y^2) <---biggest reason for confusion.

Answer (score 9):

Isaac and Ryan have already answered your question in words.  Now, in symbols, the chain rule gives:
$$\frac{d(y^2)}{dx} = \frac{d(y^2)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: +1: This is why I had the persistent feeling that my answer was missing something.

Comment: i never understood this form...and it causes all sorts of problem. The following make sense..`d/dx f(g(x))= f'(g(x)) g'(x).` But in this form it dosen't: `..= d/dy f(g(x) (d/dx g(x))` the part d/dy dosen't make sense to me i thought it was just a notation showing that derivative/Instantaneous slope of y,c,etc is this as x changes.