# Adding extra "y" value in implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

**Example**

Implicit differentiate  $x^2+y^2=6xy$

*Textbook Answer*

$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=6x\frac{dy}{dx}+6y$

then textbook just says to group the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and to solve

however, I do not understand why when you find derivative of $6xy$, you get the additional $"+6y"$. Is this a typo?

*BTW*

[Link to problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7716/implicit-differentiation)

Before I get flagged for identical question, I wanted to make sure that the nuances of the question is actually different from this one

Comment: That is the product rule. When you differentiate $6xy$, you do it as the derivative of $(6y) \times x$, so the derivative is $(6y)' \times x + 6y \times (x)'$. (note : even the  grouping $(6x) \times y$ leads to the same result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key observation we have to make here is if $$u=6x,\quad \frac{du}{dx}=6,$$ $$v=y,\quad \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx},$$ then, by virtue of the product rule $$\frac{d(6xy)}{dx}=6y+6x\frac{dy}{dx}.$$ Then, differentiating through with respect to $x$ gives $$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=6y+6x\frac{dy}{dx},$$ that is $$\frac{dy}{dx}(2y-6x)=6y-2x,$$ which of course gives $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6y-2x}{2y-6x}=\frac{3y-x}{y-3x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this, which is essentially equivalent, but may help someone out there.  If you look at taking a derivative, you can actually divide it up into two steps - the differential and dividing by dx.  For instance, take $y = x^2$.  The differential is $dy = 2x\,dx$.  The derivative is found by dividing both sides by $dx$.  $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$.  Most textbooks only teach finding the derivative as a single process, rather than separating out differentiation and dividing by $dx$ to find the derivative.  That's what makes your problem confusing.

If you have $6xy$, the differential is found using the product rule: $6(x\,dy + y\,dx)$.  When you divide by $dx$, this becomes $6x\frac{dy}{dx} + 6y \frac{dx}{dx}$, but $\frac{dx}{dx}$ cancels itself out to 1, leaving just $6x\frac{dy}{dx} + 6y$.

Separating out the differential from the derivative simplifies the process and makes it much more understandable what is going on.  For more information see [here](https://journals.blythinstitute.org/ojs/index.php/cbi/article/view/29).